# If value not true or false then.. in PHP

Tags: php

I have two functions:

```
$shipmethod = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpck_rg_lead_detail WHERE 
lead_id = $user_id and field_number = 111" );
$shipmethodo=$shipmethod[0]->value;
```

and If statement:

```
if( isset( $entry['103'] )) {

    return number_format (($entry['103'] * 0.9),0, ".", ",") ;  
}
```

I need to add an else if statement with one given value for $shipmethodo, being this one false or not true, so for that I'm using: !$ = 'value', however this is not working:

```
else if( isset( $entry['103'] ) && !$shipmethodo = 'value') {

    return number_format (($entry['103'] * 0.8),0, ".", ",") ;  
}
```

What I need to get is that if $shipmethodo 'value' is different, then condition works. 
How can I make it?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it should read `$shipmethodo != 'value'`

Comment: `$shipmethodo != 'value'`

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-bool.php <-- might be useful for you

Comment: One additional comment, `$shipmethodo` is being set to the string literal `'value'`. The comparison operator for "is equal to" is `==`. Prefixing a variable with `!` operator means "treat this as a boolean and inverse the value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `else if` statement:

`else if( isset( $entry['103'] ) && !$shipmethodo = 'value') {`

It should actually be

`else if( isset( $entry['103'] ) && $shipmethodo != 'value') {`

`!=` means "does not equal".